# Adding percent value in cell to a dollar amount in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column of currency formatted cells (C8:C15) and a markup rate of 15% which is entered into B19. I want to have the markup rate applied to C8:C15. Starting with C8 I entered the formula **=B8 + $B$19** but this merely gave me $24.15.

I know I can write *1.15 to get the correct result but this is for a school assignment and the teacher wants me to use "absolute cell referencing". Basically I have to refer to the cell C8 as the formula, not just write *1.15.

Here's a picture with the project that might help explain:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

What's the matter with using

```
=B8 * (1 + $B$19)
```

?

Comment: Feel free to [accept this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) if your problem is solved.

Comment: Accept an answer by clicking the arrow that appears on the upper left of the answer. :)